# How to consume protobuff in Scala?

Tags: scala, parsing, service, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to write Scala code to consume a protobuff file and match it to scala case classes.

I have the .proto file for the service that I am trying to consume, but am having a hard time finding a working scala compiler to generate the scala case classes from the .proto file.

I tried Scalabuf (fails in multiple points) and I'm not sure that Scala SBT can do what I need (just take a .proto file and give me case classes to add to my project).

I may be going about this the wrong way, so any advice would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up generating protobuf Java classes and using those packaged as a dependency to my main project.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial